# Commutation relation for Dirac field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator, dirac-equation, spinors

In "*Quantum Field Theory*" by Peskin and Schroeder, I couldn't understand the where they investigate the commutation (as opposed to the anticommutation) relation for the Dirac field (pg. 53):
$$
\begin{align}
  \psi(x) 
 &=
  \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}}e^{ix\cdot p} 
  \sum_{s=1,2} \left(a^s_pu^s(p)+b^s_{-p}v^s(-p)\right)
 \tag{3.87}
\\[5px]
  \psi^\dagger(y) 
 &=
  \int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_q}}e^{-iy\cdot q}
  \sum_{r=1,2}\left(a^{r\dagger}_q u^{r\dagger}(q)
                +b^{r\dagger}_{-q}v^{r\dagger}(-q)\right).
 \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

They postulate $[a^s_p,a^{r\dagger}_q]=[b^s_{p},b^{r\dagger}_{q}]=(2\pi)^3\delta^3(p-q)\delta^{sr}$ and the commutation relation is written as below (eq (3.89))
$$
\left[\psi(x),\psi^\dagger(y)\right]
=
{
\begin{align}
&
\int\frac{d^3pd^3q}{(2\pi)^6}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p2E_q}}
e^{i(x\cdot p-y\cdot q)}
\\
&
\sum_{s,r=1,2}
\left([a^s_p,a^{r\dagger}_q]u^s(p)u^{\dagger r}(q)
  +[b^s_{-p},b^{r\dagger}_{-q}]v^s(-p)v^{r\dagger}(-q)
\right)
\end{align}
}
\tag{3.89}
$$

However, I can not understand spinor calculation part. For example, the first term of
$
\psi(x)\psi^\dagger(y)- \psi^\dagger(y)\psi(x)
$
is
$$
\sum_{s,r=1,2}\left(
a^s_pu^s(p) a^{r\dagger}_qu^{r\dagger}(q) - a^{r\dagger}_qu^{r\dagger}(q) a^s_pu^s(p)
\right)
\,,
\tag{4}
$$
and it becomes
$$
\sum_{s,r=1,2} (a^s_pa^{r\dagger}_q - a^{r\dagger}_qa^s_p)u^s(p) u^{\dagger r}(q)
\,.
\tag{5}
$$

But I think $u^s(p) u^{\dagger r}(q) \neq  u^{\dagger r}(q) u^s(p)$. Then, how can it reach to the part?

And if $u^s(p) u^{\dagger r}(q) = u^{\dagger r}(q) u^s(p)$, why they don't do $\sum_{s,r=1,2} u^{\dagger r}(q) u^s(p)$, which gives a scalar quantity?

Comment: Have you tried putting spinor indices everywhere? That may help you solve you confusion about moving spinors around.

Comment: This is confusing to me also because $u^s(p) u^{\dagger r}(q)$ seems to be an outer product and  $u^{\dagger r}(q) u^s(p)$ seems to be an inner product.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in general $(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger$, so your $\psi^\dagger$ expression is not entirely correct.

Secondly, the spinors $u^s, v^s, u^{r\dagger}, v^{r\dagger}$ are not operators but just numbers (columns of numbers technically) hence they commute with the creation and annihilation operators. The creation/annihilation operators act on the vacuum (or any other) state $|0\rangle$, not on the spinors.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, we're considering the commutator relation of $\Psi_a(x)$, which is just one component of $\Psi(x)$. In this understanding, Commutator relation read:
$$ [\Psi_a(x),\Psi_b(y)] = \delta^4(x-y) \delta_{ab} $$

Comment: The components of u and v are just numbers, hence commute.